# Copy HashMap of different type

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

How can I copy content of one `HashMap<String,AddressDTO>` to another  `HashMap<String,AddressBO>` of a different type. There is no
inheritance between `AdressDTO` and `AddressBO` ,both are POJOs with the same set of attributes:

```
AddressDTO addDTO = new AddressDTO();
addDTO.setAdd1("add1");
addDTO.setAdd2("add2");
addDTO.setAddtype("pri");
addDTO.setCity("city");


Map<String,Object> map1  = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map1.put("primary", addDTO);

Map<String,Object> map2  = new HashMap<String,Object>(map1);
AddressBO addnew = (AddressBO) map2.get("primary");
//this will give me runtime error AddressDTO cannot be cast to AddressBO    
System.out.println(addnew.getAdd1());
System.out.println(addnew.getAdd2());
System.out.println(addnew.getAddtype());
```

Comment: Do you have control over all the code? Or do you need to stick to given classes unchanged?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the results of entry set which will give you the key value pairs and allow you to copy.

Also, HashMap takes a map. Probably other maps do too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast one Object to another based on field similarity only. You should use inheritance, or use some kind of transformer to create `AddressBO` from `AddressDTO`

If both Object contains exactly the same fields, there is no need for two classes.

Answer (score 0):

There are various tools available that will use reflection to copy the values.

Alternatively you could just set the reference in the new map to be the same as the old map (then they will both share the same `HashMap`).

But it sounds like your real problem is mapping from the DTO to the BO.

For example if you create a constructor for the BO that accepts a DTO and creates a new BO from it then you could just do:

```
for (Entry<String, DTO> e: map1) {
    map2.put(e.getKey(), new BO(e.getValue()));
}
```

Comment: it worked if I add constructor in BO class that accepts Object and further casted to DTO. And modified above code as                 for(Entry<String, Object> e: map1.entrySet()) {
map2.put(e.getKey(), new AddressBO(e.getValue()));
}//otherwise it was prompting map1 not iteratable.                                                         Thanks but can there be other solution...

Comment: There are many ways to do it, none are particularly neat though.